# Setting header in the Http Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

We are calling the Odata endpoint from our application. The odata endpoint has few headers needed like below

[image]

I am able to add the content on to my application which calls the end point like below

```
               ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
                Uri uri = new Uri(BaseURL_Core);
                client_Core.BaseAddress = uri;
                client_Core.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client_Core.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client_Core.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray_Core));
```

How to set here the `Prefer` that will set the maxpagesize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use method `Add` on `DefaultRequestHeades` collection to add custom ones.

```
client_Core.DefaultRequestHeades.Add("Prefer", "odata.maxpagesize=500")
```